# How to add string + id combination with int autoincrement no repeat in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, spring-boot, sequence

```
    List<StudentRoom> students=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int roomCount=0;roomCount<=studentRoomCount;roomCount++){
        StudentRoom studentRoom=new StudentRoom();
        studentRoom.setRoomName("Class "+roomCount);     
        studentRoom.add(studentRoom);
    }
studentRoomRoomRepoService.saveAll(students);
```

Here example want to roomName like Class 1,Class 2..... and so on
when I delete classes It will start from Class 1 Or If I add more class It start from last added Class For Ex : Last Added Class was "Class 4" when I add one more class it must start from Class 4

How can I do this in java

Comment: Doesn't your implementation already do that?

Comment: Yes, but, How to manage If I add more class It start from last added Class For Ex : Last Added Class was "Class 4" when I add one more class it must start from Class 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your class names are always consequent and in that case, your list size will tell you the last class name, and accordingly, you can name the next class.

```
studentRoom.setRoomName("Class "+ students.size()+1);
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, It's works but one query How to manage if i have 3 Class Ex : Class 1,Class 2 and Class 3 and if i delete class 2 As above logic it's create duplicate "Class 3" How To mange This

Comment: Have one static field saying `roomCounter` inside StudentRoom Class and inside setRoomName method you can increase that value to keep track of the room no. But this way you can avoid that duplicate issue but I would suggest you to use some unique id which is more appropriate.